# Is there an on_bot_leave event in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I've searched a lot on stack overflow, but cant seem to find anything about this. Is there an event that makes something happen when the bot leaves the server?

I have it so that when a command is run, it sets a variable to be on, and when that variable is on it makes a message happen in every channel created like so:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def channel(ctx):
    global Toggle
    Toggle = True
    await ctx.send("Channel messages enabled!")

@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if Toggle == True:
        await channel.send("HELLO :D")
    else:
        pass
```

Problem is, when !channel is run, it makes this server wide. How would i make it so that when a bot leaves, toggle is reverted to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`on_guild_remove`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_remove) event that fires when:

- The client got banned.
- The client got kicked.
- The client left the guild.
- The client or the guild owner deleted the guild.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild: discord.Guild):
    # one of the above has just happened
    global Toggle
    print(f"Removed from: {guild.id}")
    Toggle = False
```

For reference, all the possible events are [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference). Very useful to consult when looking to add functionality and you're not sure if there's an existing event or not. Additionally, the [discord events docs are here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#receive-events).

On a side note, with Python you don't need to do `if Toggle == True:`. If `Toggle` is a boolean (or can be inferred to be either True/False) then `if Toggle:` is sufficient.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if Toggle:
        await channel.send("HELLO :D")
```

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) with more details.